# 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable nginx/1.13.9 in jenkins x

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, jenkins-x

I have created kubernetes cluster using minikube and installed Jenkins x on it.

I am not able to access the Jenkins x dashboard.

> Error `503 Service Temporarily Unavailable nginx/1.13.9`.

*note:* I have tried with restarting minikube cluster also.

Comment: How did you install Jenkins X?  My guess is there's not enough resources to run all the pods, there's an option to create the cluster using jx too, `jx create cluster minikube` https://jenkins-x.io/getting-started/create-cluster/#using-minikube-local . This will set the minikube resources required to run Jenkins X.
FWIW to check if the pods aren't running run `kubectl get pods`

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by [James Rawlings](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5010477/james-rawlings) in the comments, it's likely to be a resource issue. The recommendations in the [manual](https://jenkins-x.io/getting-started/create-cluster/#using-minikube-local) are:

> A known good configuration on a 2015 model Macbook Pro is to use **8 GB** of RAM, **8 cores**, a **150 GB** disk size and [hyperkit](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/blob/master/docs/drivers.md#hyperkit-driver).
>
> The disk size is particularly large as a number of images will need to be downloaded.
>
> So we highly recommend using one of the public clouds above to try out Jenkins X. They all have free tiers so it should not cost you any significant cash and it’ll give you a chance to try out the cloud.

Default minikube installation uses only 2048 MB of RAM, 2 CPU cores and 20Gb disk space. You can adjust minikube VM size using command line options:

```
$ minikube start --cpus=8 --memory=8192 --disk-size=150g --vm-driver=hyperkit
```

or use `jx` tool for that:

For MacOS

```
$ brew install docker-machine-driver-hyperkit

# docker-machine-driver-hyperkit need root owner and uid 
$ sudo chown root:wheel /usr/local/opt/docker-machine-driver-hyperkit/bin/docker-machine-driver-hyperkit
$ sudo chmod u+s /usr/local/opt/docker-machine-driver-hyperkit/bin/docker-machine-driver-hyperkit

$ brew tap jenkins-x/jx
$ brew install jx

$ jx create cluster minikube
```

For linux:

```
$ curl -L https://github.com/jenkins-x/jx/releases/download/v1.3.784/jx-linux-amd64.tar.gz | tar xzv 
$ sudo mv jx /usr/local/bin

$ jx create cluster minikube
```